# Date is off by one day on server but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datetime

I just started a new job at this software company and we realized that just a couple days ago that the dates on some of our service reports were off by a day.  When I run the application on localhost all the dates are correct, so I can only speculate that the issue is coming from the server end.

We have all dates and times converted to UTC already so I don't think that this is an issue.

```
export const FormatDate = (stringDate) => {
    if (stringDate && stringDate != "") {
        var date = new Date(stringDate);
        if (date.getFullYear() < 2015) { return "" }

        var monthNames = ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May.", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug.", "Sep.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Dec."];
        var dateToPass = monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + (date.getDate() ) + ", " + date.getFullYear();

        if (dateToPass === "Jan. 1, 1000") {
            return "";
        }
        return dateToPass;
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is currently how we are formatting our dates.  I would assume that this wouldn't cause any issues but then again I'm slightly new to JavaScript so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like server is in different time zone?

Comment: If you're *starting off* with a "string date", why do you need to format it? That seems like a fundamental design flaw.

Comment: are the servers synced with NTP?

Comment: How exactly are you sending the dates from the server to client.  IOW: What format is `stringDate`

Comment: @epascarello I believe we use aws ec2 oregon location for our instances

Comment: @Satya I'm not positive, but their are other tables on our console that have the correct dates, and then there are others with a day diff.

Comment: @Keith the format is in ISO.  I did a console log of what the input is and it looks something like this: 2019-07-29T05:00:00.000Z.  On the dev console it displays the correct date, but if I go to the actual site it displays the date as the 28th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said (in the question comments) that you are passing in strings in like this `"2019-07-29T05:00:00.000Z"`.  The trailing `Z` indicates UTC, which is good.

You've created a `Date` object by parsing this string, and then you then call the `getMonth`, `getDate`, and `getFullYear` functions.  These functions return values based on the local time zone of the computer where the code is running.  Thus, you are doing a UTC to local-time conversion.

You can simply switch to the `getUTCMonth`, `getUTCDate`, and `getUTCFullYear` functions instead.  Then the results will match the value you provided in your UTC-based input string.

```
var dateToPass = monthNames[date.getUTCMonth()] + " " + (date.getUTCDate() ) + ", " + date.getUTCFullYear();
```

Comment: Ok I will give this a try

Comment: I noticed that "date" when returned is:   Mon Jul 29 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time).  Wouldn't this mean that it would actually be the 28th in local time?

Comment: You're looking at a string representation, not the object itself.  Assuming you are looking at the dev console, there is an implicit `.toString()` being called (though some console implementations call `.toUTCString()` instead).  The `Date` object only ever keeps track of one value - the UTC-based timestamp as a number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00 UTC.  You can see that with `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()`.

Comment: (`.toString()` does a local time conversion while creating the string.)

Comment: Is there a way to see if this works without rebuilding the server?  As stated before it doesn't change anything on localhost since all the dates are correct on there, it's only affected on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `Data` instance, you also add the current time zone according to your system.

For example, consider the following UTC time string: `Mon, 29 Jul 2019 13:00:00 GMT`

If you use this string to create a new `Date` object and then get the local time, you may end up with a different time string

```
const d = new Date('Mon, 29 Jul 2019 13:00:00 GMT')
// this will return string is according to your time zone, i got 16:00:00 GMT+0300
d.toTimeString();
```

So you might use UTC and still get different time strings for different clients.

Comment: I'm pulling the dates from mysql, which are the correct date, and they are being passed as a parameter for the FormatDate function above.  The dates that are grabbed from the db are in the form year-month-day.

Comment: the problem is with the line `var date = new Date(stringDate);`. When you create a new Date, you added the current browser / system timezone

Comment: So should I just get rid of this line?

Comment: I saw using `date.getUTCDate()` fixed your issue. Good luck :)